# Python Optimization - Will calling functions for iteration slow my program significantly?

Tags: python, optimization, iteration

Comparing these 2 codebases:

```
# Call this A.
def main():
    for a in list:
        foo(a)

def foo(something):
    <perform lots of operations on something and return a result>
```

VS

```
# Call this B
def main():
    for a in list:
        <perform lots of operations on a and return a result>
```

How much slower is A than B? Obviously A has function overhead, but is this worth taking into account when writing code? I ask this because I currently have implemented by program in the A version, where basically for every iteration, a function is called. I'd much rather do this, as the "" is very complex and in depth, so putting it in the for loop is very messy. Not to mention I could not reuse the code later for other iterations...

Comment: use `timeit.timeit` to find out.  generally the overhead of the function call is negligible if the function itself has a lot of operations.  Don't optimize prematurely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your 'lots of operations' happen blazingly fast, the expense of an extra function call would be negligible.

When writing, pay more attention to big-O asymptotic efficiencies; do not try to optimize non-obvious things. Then, if your program is slow, ***profile it*** and address the biggest bottleneck(s). Optimization without prior profiling  is a futile effort.

Comment: Blazingly fast and the list is ridiculously long! Who cares if 5 things happen really fast?

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer readability/maintainability/unittestability. Only if it's absolutely necessary for that extra performance, should you inline the function.

The extra overhead of `foo` is probably negligible given `"<perform lots of operations on something..."`